# Socket.Accept Throws Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

First of all, i'm new to all this Stack Overflow thingy.

I'm mostly a Unity programmer, but i need to run some code on my Pi and Unity can't build for it. Therefore, i'm using C# so i can later build with Mono.

I have a basic socket server code that runs off of unity, and it works fine. 
I tried porting it over to VS but i always get a Null Ref Exception when calling Socket.Accept.

```
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;


class RasPi
{
    IPAddress ipAddress;
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint;

    Socket listener;
    Socket handler;

    int i = 0;

    string data = string.Empty;

    public string IP = "192.168.10.5";
    public int Port = 5001;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new RasPi().Initialize();
        new RasPi().StartListening();
    }


    void Initialize()
    {
        i = 0;

        ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
        localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Port);


        listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                             SocketType.Stream,
                             ProtocolType.Tcp);

        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(10);
    }

    public void StartListening()
    {

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(listener.Accept());
                    handler = listener.Accept();
                }

                data = string.Empty;


                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);

                    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

                    ProcessData(data);

                    handler.Send(bytes);

                    break;
                }


                //Restart();
                Console.ReadKey();
                break;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }


   /* void Restart()
    {    
        i++;
        StartListening();
    }*/

    public void ProcessData(string data)
    {
        switch (data)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Errors occur whenever i call listener.Accept();

In Unity, this worked fine. Anyone willing to help me here?

PS: I'm new to Networking, so i'm probably doing something stupid and i don't realise it.

Comment: That's because you call `Initialize` not on the same `RasPi` instance you later call `StartListening`. Change to `var rp = new RasPi(); rp.Initialize(); rp.StartListening();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create 2 `RasPi` objects and call `Initialize()` and `StartListening()` on them individually. The second object won't have the same state as the first object that called `Initialize()` so `StartListening()` fails miserably. Instead, create one object and call both methods on it:

```
var rasPi = new RasPi();
rasPi.Initialize();
rasPi.StartListening();
```

Comment: You are correct! Silly me added that in because it complained i needed a reference to access those methods.